# Clarification on '**Excessive shift value' Lint warning**

Tags: lint

Clarification on '**Excessive shift value' Lint warning**-

Initial parameters as below,

```
*#define SCC_BUFFERSIZE 0x80*  

*uint16 DeviceConfigMsg[10];*
```

Also please see below coding part

```
**DeviceConfigMsg[0] =  SCC_BUFFER_SIZE;*
*DeviceConfigMsg[1] =  SCC_R_OK;*
*DeviceConfigMsg[2] =  SCC_BUFFERSIZE & 0xFF;*
*DeviceConfigMsg[3] = (SCC_BUFFERSIZE>>8) & 0xFF;**
```

When executing the code, I am getting lint warning for the last line 
`****DeviceConfigMsg[3] = (SCC_BUFFERSIZE>>8) & 0xFF****`  as below .
Warning 572: prio2: Excessive shift value (precision 8 shifted right by 8)

I know that 0x80 <<8 = 0 always currently , but I cannot assign zero explicitly now because the value of the macro **SCC_BUFFERSIZE** may change later.
so please let me know how to solve this lint error. 
Let me know if you need any other inputs from my end.
I am using GHS compiler.

Thanks in advance,

JEEE

Comment: Isn't the point that 0x80 is an 8-bit value so shifting it right 8 bits will always yield a value of zero?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to suppress this one:

```
DeviceConfigMsg[3] = (SCC_BUFFERSIZE>>8) & 0xFF; //lint !e572
```

It's a 'bug' in the value tracking system.

Both of the following *should* work, according to the documentation:

```
#define SCC_BUFFERSIZE (0x0080)

const uint16 SCC_BUFFERSIZE = 0x80;
```

as this lets Lint know that SCC_BUFFERSIZE could be up to 16 bits, and it should be happy to shift it by only 8.

Unfortunately, neither actually does work.

As they're constants Lint seems to work out the actual values, shrinks them, then issues the warning.

If you remove the 'const' from the constant it works fine:

```
uint16 SCC_BUFFERSIZE = 0x80;
```

because it assumes they could be any valid uint16.

That makes the code worse though, so the suppression is a better fix in this case.

Comment: so what is the final and best solution you meant to convey?

Comment: Just suppress the message with //lint !e572